# Continue Working on a sub branch while waiting a pull

Tags: git, github

I have made my first pull request to a public github repo. I forked, coded and submited all my work on a branch. Lets call it BranchA.

While I am waiting on the request to go through I would like to do more work on a new branch that includes BranchA's changes. Should I create BranchB from BranchA?

If the above is correct when I pull the changes from the upstream what happens to BranchB assuming BranchA has been merged?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git doesn't have a concept of a "sub-branch"; branches don't have parents.

If you create branch B from branch A, branch B will include all of branch A's commits.
If you then make more commits in branch A, you can `git merge` (or rebase) them into branch B.
Similarly, if the upstream master gets more commits, you can `git merge` them into either branch (you'll need to `git fetch` them first).

When the pull request is accepted, the commits will then be in the upstream master as well.

Comment: In the question's scenario, say you do a pull request with B while A's pull is still waiting to be accepted. B's pull will then also include A's commits. What happens when A gets accepted and merged? Will A's commits not show up as diffs in B, or will A's commits be merged again when B is merged?

Comment: this is similar scenario I'm facing. I have Branch A, from that mistaken I created subbranch B. Now when i check to give merge request for Branch B it also showing commit of Branch A. Another developer still working on Branch A. What will happened if I merge Branch B. Please suggest.

Comment: @Nirav: Then some of the commits will already be present.  That isn't a problem. You can also use `git rebase` to remove them.